# BLE Win API can not get notification

Tags: c#, winapi, bluetooth

I'm developing a windows 10 destop application using Win API for BLE communication. I use a BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher adWatcher to scan for nearby BLE devices. After some UI work, I use the below code to connect to certain device and perform read/write to certain characteristic. The writing part works fine but the ValueChanged event is never triggered, knowing that the BLE device should be sending notificaitons.

I tried similar code in Java on Android Platform. Both the writing and nofication worked. I read through all the bluetooth related Win API documents and still can't find out what's wrong with the code.

If any one has any idea about it, so please help me.

```
async public static void Connect(UInt64 bleAddress)
{
    adWatcher.Stop();
    currentBle = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(bleAddress);
    GattDeviceServicesResult result = await currentBle.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        GattCharacteristicsResult chResult = await result.Services[0].GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        if (chResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            cha = chResult.Characteristics[0];
            Debug.WriteLine(cha.Uuid.ToString());

            cha.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;
            GattCommunicationStatus status = await cha.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();
            writer.WriteString("hello");
            GattCommunicationStatus wResult = await cha.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

            if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("OK");
            }
           else
                Debug.WriteLine("error");
        }
    }
    else
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Status.ToString());
}


static void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender,  GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{            
    Debug.Write("Triggered!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk
it's a known issue. I had the same problem since 10 minutes ago, after three days of struggling, then i tried using what Matthew Beaver suggest:

```
"O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0x7;;;PS)(A;;0x3;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x3;;;AC)(A;;0x3;;;LS)(A;;0x3;;;NS)"

CoInitializeSecurity(
    absoluteSddl, // Converted from the above string.
    -1,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,
    NULL,
    EOAC_NONE,
    nullptr);`
```

This is how I used it:

```
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr pVoid, int
            cAuthSvc, IntPtr asAuthSvc, IntPtr pReserved1, RPCAUTHNLEVEL level,
            RPCIMPLEVEL impers, IntPtr pAuthList, EOAUTHNCAP dwCapabilities, IntPtr
            pReserved3);

        public enum RPCAUTHNLEVEL
        {
            Default = 0,
            None = 1,
            Connect = 2,
            Call = 3,
            Pkt = 4,
            PktIntegrity = 5,
            PktPrivacy = 6
        }

        public enum RPCIMPLEVEL
        {
            Default = 0,
            Anonymous = 1,
            Identify = 2,
            Impersonate = 3,
            Delegate = 4
        }

        public enum EOAUTHNCAP
        {
            None = 0x00,
            MutualAuth = 0x01,
            StaticCloaking = 0x20,
            DynamicCloaking = 0x40,
            AnyAuthority = 0x80,
            MakeFullSIC = 0x100,
            Default = 0x800,
            SecureRefs = 0x02,
            AccessControl = 0x04,
            AppID = 0x08,
            Dynamic = 0x10,
            RequireFullSIC = 0x200,
            AutoImpersonate = 0x400,
            NoCustomMarshal = 0x2000,
            DisableAAA = 0x1000
        }
```

And then, before anything else start in your application:

```
 CoInitializeSecurity(
                IntPtr.Zero,
                -1,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                RPCAUTHNLEVEL.Default,
                RPCIMPLEVEL.Identify,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                EOAUTHNCAP.None,
                IntPtr.Zero);
```

Apparently is now working, I still have to investigate how this is gonna affect my existing application`(that worked prior Windows Creator Update).

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Since mine is a Winform application, I take Matthew Beaver's suggestion to edit the registry instead.